# AngularJS and PHP object oriented scripts and sessions

Tags: angularjs

Okay. It's a theory based question about AngularJS. So, if I had a PHP based web app, and I want to use angularJS with it instead of pure JS and jQuery scripts.

1. First of all, how to save sessions while logging in ?
2. And why an OOP PHP class could not work with angular, because we didn't specify which function to execute. so I need now to split all my classes into functions that echo a `json` result ?
3. Does angular append data directly into my page without using any jQuery basics of `.append()` or `.after() or... ?

Please, I am new to angularJS, and I really need to know how to manage each of those problems. I know some people gonna downvote, but some others will reply.

Comment: Okay.... Both are different. `angular` client side and `php` server side. You can save sessions in `PHP` as simple as you did it before ( I guess ). You can use `$http` service of angular to interact with server. See PHP's OOP function executable on server. You can hit any class or function from REST client but all you need to tell PHP to access those functions outside. Angular can touch your PHP class and function. For the json, you could use php's `json_encode` function . And to append HTML in DOM, you should go with angular's `directives`

Comment: But I need to send per example the user and pass using angular not Ajax. And I still need to add headers in each page to say if session is empty go to logout page ?

Comment: Aren't you using any php framework ? They are having such functionalities by default. You can also use authentication token for verification.

Comment: So I can use Laravel with angular normally ?

Comment: yeah sure. There are many articles you will get.